# changing badge colors from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var colorr = ["#008000", "#e0ffc1", "#ffc1e1", "#cc0000"];
   $.each(sortable.reverse(), function(key, value){
     $('#results').append("<li><h3>" +  value[0] + ": <span class='badge' 
       style='background-color: var(cl); font-size: 25px ;'>"+ value[1] + "% 
</span></h3></li>");
               })
```

the output of this code will be like:

[image]

i.e displaying the four percentage with badge.

now while iterating the loop in the below code, i want to change the badge color of these fours numbers from the colorr array declared in the code.

how to achieve this ?

Comment: what is `sortable`? can you setup a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`background-color: '+colorr[key]+';`

Example working code

```
var colorr = ["#008000", "#e0ffc1", "#ffc1e1", "#cc0000"];
$(colorr).each(function (key, value) {
    $('body').append('<li><h3><span class="badge" style="background-color:' + colorr[key] + '; font-size: 25px ;">Hi</span></h3></li>');
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PZc8B/3/)

Comment: @Vikneshwaren if helps upvote it accept as answer bro